# JMS wildcards values

Tags: mule, esb

in mule I can listen to multiple JMS queus using wildcards like this:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint  queue="Consumer.sandy-proxy.MES.*.PRINTER.LABELS.*" connector-ref="jmsConnector" />
```

how can I get the real queue destination name? es. MES.**AV**.PRINTER.LABELS.**PRINTER1**?

I need to know the two bolded params, but I can't find them anywhere. Thank you

```
INFO  2015-12-04 10:26:17,959 [sandy-subscriber.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=d4a47ed4-9a66-11e5-a5b5-879af7c5a144
  payload=java.lang.String
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    ActiveMQ.MQTT.QoS=0
    JMSDeliveryMode=1
    JMSDestination=queue://Consumer.sandy-proxy.MES.*.PRINTER.LABELS.*
    JMSExpiration=0
    JMSMessageID=ID:itviacvlt0014-60763-1449158672950-4:5:-1:1:5
    JMSPriority=4
    JMSRedelivered=false
    JMSTimestamp=1449220220299
    MULE_MESSAGE_ID=ID:itviacvlt0014-60763-1449158672950-4:5:-1:1:5
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.jms.Consumer.sandy.proxy.MES.PRINTER.LABELS
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
  SESSION scoped properties:
```

Answer (score 0):

What mule version your using?

I am using Anypoint Studio version 5.3.2 and run time 3.6.1 and I can see the JMS queue name as part of JMSDestination value.

My JMS receiver queue wild card entry

```
activemq.*.testing
```

and when I print the logs I can see

```
INBOUND scoped properties:
JMSDeliveryMode=2
JMSDestination=queue://activemq.rk100.testing
JMSExpiration=0
JMSMessageID=ID:PC04899-51895-1449232247109-1:1:5:1:1
JMSPriority=4
JMSRedelivered=false
JMSTimestamp=1449232255753
```

Comment: thank you. You are right, but don't solve the problem. The issue is on ActiveMQ and virtual topics